# Display content based on remote url in php?

Tags: php, coldfusion

I currently have two php files (header and footer) on my server that is used as a template and is retrieved on another server that wraps the template files around their software.

Is it possible to display different content based on their url in my template files in php? If so, how?

I don't know if this matters, but the other server uses coldfusion and not php.

Comment: I tagged w/Cold Fusion, as maybe someone who knows that well will be able to tell us if CF would send any kind of identifying information when requesting the parsed html from your server.

Answer (score 1):

The php file could check a parameter in the url, like template.php?url=stackoverflow , so in the php file you could check

```
if ($_GET['url']=='stackoverflow'){
    echo "Stack Overflow template";
}else if ($_GET['url']=='lol'){
    echo "Another template";
}else{
    echo "error";
}
```

**Edit:**
Now the server getting the content, just needs to add that parameter to the url and it gets the template that it wants. You could set a default template in case no parameter is specified.

Comment: The problem is that they will not do that on their end. I can only make changes on my end and they retrieve what I have.

Comment: so what kind of "calls" do you get or how do they get your template at the moment?

Comment: Sorry about that (see my question edit), but its actually two php files hosted on my server and they wrap them around their application. To be honest, I'm not sure how they get the templates. All they needed from me was the urls of the header and footer files.

Comment: If you don't know how they get the content, it's hard to change your script. Also, what header and footer do at the moment? They just 'echo' a html layout?

Comment: I see. Yes, they just 'echo' a html layout.

Comment: You can't trust it 100%, but you can try using the variable $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to see who is making the call, and echo a different layout based on the value of this variable. More info here http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: I tried HTTP_SERVER but it doesn't show anything. I went ahead and tried all the other $_SERVER calls to see what came up. I don't know if these would help but these came up: REMOTE_PORT, REMOTE_ADDR, HTTP_CONNECTION, REQUEST_METHOD

Comment: try `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]`. That should get the domain name.

Comment: When I try $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"], it shows my domain name where the template files are hosted on my server.

Comment: Oh, right that wouldn't work if the php is parsing on _your_ server and sending them plain html; And I see from a previous question that is the process.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible for their url to contain a get variable like `www.theirwebsite.com/?chrome=red`? then your file could read that and parse out different themes based on what the variable's value is.

Comment: Unfortunately, they won't do it.

Comment: @amye Is it possible for the them to request a different theme file depending on what *they* need?

Comment: No, they won't modify anything on their end. I can only make changes to the template files hosted on my server.

Answer (score 0):

NOt quite sure if I'm understanding you, but you can certainly display different content based on a url.

```
$remote_content = file_get_contents($someurl);
switch $someurl
    case 'www.google.com':
           display_google_content();
           break;
    case 'www.microsoft.com':
           throw(BSOD);
           break;
    default:
           display_standard_content();
}
```

Comment: This code isn't going to work on it's own. It's just an example with faked functions.

Comment: I know, thanks. I did modify it to my needs, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two obvious possibilities for how the remote server is attaching your code that spring to mind.  The first is using JavaScript to instruct the client to go out and get your content, then write it to the appropriate locations.  This should be rather obvious when looking at the HTML source code generated by their application.

The more likely scenario, in my opinion, is that they use CFHTTP to retrieve the content and inject it directly.  CFHTTP mimics a broser call -- it's a standard HTTP 1.1 request.  It's not going to contain a reference to the url requested on their server.  Unless you can convince them to add identifying information to the request, all you'll be able to tell on your server is that the request came from CF (by examining the remote agent).